# Illegal worker definition

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

A visitor to the UK stays with a UK citizen, offers cleaning services in exchange for room & board. Would a work visa be required for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appendix to immigration rule [for visitors](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) V4.5-6 lists prohibited activities. One of the first prohibitions (f) is against providing goods or services, with a note that there is a set of permitted exceptions. The more [generic page on standard visitors](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa) states that you can't do paid or unpaid work. Appendix 3 of the rules page says what is allowed, which includes such things as scientists "gather(ing) information and facts for a specific project which directly relates to their employment overseas", but does not include "working as household help in exchange for room and board". There are [provisions for domestic workers](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/overseas-domestic-workers-in-private-households-wrk21/overseas-domestic-workers-in-private-households-wrk21--2) to accompany an employer, which would not be applicable. In light of these restrictions on trading services for something of value (i.e. payment), I would conclude that the activity is prohibited.